# Want to update table row in asp .net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have 2 columns in my table named `CreatedOn` and `ModifiedOn`. Of course, In the form I dont want to show these two fields even as in hidden filed. When I post the same form I want to change `ModifiedOn` by Current DateTime and Want to keep `CreatedOn` value as it is. But as I have no hidden filed name CreatedOn, it sets it to null in the database. So I then I used the code below

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{ 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var OldInsObj = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
                DateTime UsersDateCreated = (DateTime)db.Entry(OldInsObj).Property("UsersDateCreated").CurrentValue;

                user.UsersDateCreated = UsersDateCreated;

                user.UsersDateModified = DateTime.Now;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

How can I solve this?

Please don't give any blog link to read, I have already read some of them but could not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to resolve this issue. You can detach the old object before you attach the new instance

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{ 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var OldInsObj = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
            DateTime UsersDateCreated = OldInsObj.UsersDateCreated;

            user.UsersDateCreated = UsersDateCreated;
            user.UsersDateModified = DateTime.Now;

            db.Entry(OldInsObj).State = EntityState.Detached;

            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
 }
```

You can update the entity instance retrieved from database.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int userId)
{ 
        var user = db.Users.Find(userId);

        if (TryUpdateModel(user))
        {                
            user.UsersDateCreated = UsersDateCreated;

            user.UsersDateModified = DateTime.Now;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
 }
```

Or you can use Automapper to copy the values of `user` instance to the `OldInsObj` instance.

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{ 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var OldInsObj = db.Users.Find(user.UserId);
            DateTime UsersDateCreated = OldInsObj.UsersDateCreated;

            OldInsObj = Mapper.Map(user);

            OldInsObj.UsersDateCreated = UsersDateCreated;
            OldInsObj.UsersDateModified = DateTime.Now;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
 }
```

Comment: i think this would be only solution on the stackoverflow. I have gone through many answers but none of them was so precise as this one. Thank you so much.

Comment: would you please tell me that the way I am doing is right? I just started working with .net mvc.

Comment: @RajanRawal Attaching and detaching is error-prone. I would use the second or third method suggested in the answer.

Comment: `Mapper.Map(user);` show red line below `Mapper`, Do I need to import any namespace?

Comment: I installed Automapper, then what to do i dont know. Should I add `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();` in `Application_Start()` function?

Comment: @RajanRawal Yes. Please go through an article on AutoMapper to get started.